# Issue loading classes order EDIT: works, although some odd behavior along the way

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I'm working on a project to recreate some of the functionality of ActiveRecord. Here's the portion that isn't working

```
module Associations
  def belongs_to(name, params)
    self.class.send(:define_method, :other_class) do |name, params|
      (params[:class_name] || name.camelize).constantize
    end

    self.class.send(:define_method, :other_table_name) do |other_class|
      other_class.table_name
    end
    .
    .
    .
    o_c = other_class(name, params)
    #puts this and other (working) values in a query
    query = <<-SQL
      ...
    SQL
    #sends it off with db.execute(query)...
```

I'm building towards this testing file:

```
require 'all_files' #holds SQLClass & others

pets_db_file_name = File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "pets.db"))
DBConnection.open(pets_db_file_name)

#class Person
#end

class Pet < SQLClass
  set_table_name("pets")
  set_attrs(:id, :name, :owner_id)

  belongs_to :person, :class_name => "Person", :primary_key => :id, :foreign_key => :owner_id
end

class Person < SQLClass
  set_table_name("people")
  set_attrs(:id, :name)

  has_many :pets, :foreign_key => :owner_id
end
.
.
.
```

Without any changes I received

```
.../active_support/inflector/methods.rb:230:in `block in constantize': uninitialized constant Person (NameError)
```

Just to make sure that it was an issue with the order of loading the classes in the file I began the file with the empty Person class, which, as predicted gave me

```
undefined method `table_name' for Person:Class (NoMethodError)
```

Since this is a learning project I don't want to change the test to make my code work (open all the classes, set all the tables/attributes then reopen them them for `belongs_to`. But, I'm stuck on how else to proceed.)

EDIT SQLClass:

```
class SQLClass < AssignmentClass

    extend SearchMod

    extend Associations

    def self.set_table_name(table_name)
         @table_name = table_name
    end

    def self.table_name
        @table_name
    end
#some more methods for finding rows, and creating new rows in existing tables
```

And the relevant part of AssignmentClass uses `send` on `attr_accessor` to give functionality to `set_attrs` and makes sure that before you `initialize` a new instance of a class all the names match what was set using `set_attrs`.

Comment: Well, what’s in `SQLClass`/how does `Associations` end up being in the models?

Comment: I use extend Associations in SQLClass, I'll edit with the relevant parts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Progress! Inspired by Alex D's suggestion to use `method_missing` to delay the creation I instead used `define_method`to create a method for the name, like so:

```
define_method, :other_class) do |name, params|
          (params[:class_name] || name.camelize).constantize
        end

define_method(:other_table_name) do |other_class|
  other_class.table_name
end

#etc

define_method(name) do #|params| turns out I didn't need to pass in `params` at all but:
        #p "---#{params} (This is line 31: when testing this out I got the strangest error
#.rb:31:in `block in belongs_to': wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) (ArgumentError)
#if anyone can explain this I would be grateful.
#I had declared an @params class instance variable and a getter for it,
#but nothing that should make params require an argument
        f_k = foreign_key(name, params)
        p f_k
        o_c = other_class(name, params)
        o_t_n = other_table_name(o_c)
        p_k = primary_key(params)

        query = <<-SQL
            SELECT *
            FROM #{o_t_n}
            WHERE #{p_k} = ?
        SQL

        row = DBConnection.execute(query, self.send(f_k))
        o_c.parse_all(row)
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

This highlights an important difference between dynamic, interpreted Ruby (et al) and static, compiled languages like Java/C#/C++. In Java, the compiler runs over all your source files, finds all the class/method definitions, and matches them up with usages. Ruby doesn't work like this -- a class "comes into existence" after executing its `class` block. Before that, the Ruby interpreter doesn't know anything about it.

In your test file, you define `Pet` first. Within the definition of `Pet`, you have `belongs_to :person`. `belongs_to` does `:person.constantize`, attempting to get the class object for `Person`. But `Person` doesn't exist yet! Its definition comes later in the test file.

There are a couple ways I can think that you could try to resolve this:

One would be to do what Rails does: define each class in its own file, and make the file names conform to some convention. Override `constant_missing`, and make it automatically load the file which defines the missing class. This will make load order problems resolve themselves automatically.

Another solution would be to make `belongs_to` lazy. Rather than looking up the `Person` class object immediately, it could just record the fact that there is an association between `Pet` and `Person`. When someone tries to call `pet.person`, use a `missing_method` hook to actually define the method. (Presumably, by that time all the class definitions will have been executed.)

Another way would be do something like:

```
define_method(belongs_to) do
  belongs_to_class = belongs_to.constantize
  self.class.send(:define_method, belongs_to) do
    # put actual definition here
  end
  self.send(belongs_to)
end
```

This code is not tested, it's just to give you an idea! Though it's a pretty mind-bending idea, perhaps. Basically, you define a method which redefines itself the first time it is called. Just like using `method_missing`, this allows you to delay the class lookup until the first time the method is actually used.

If I can say one more thing: though you say you don't want to "overload" `method_missing`, I don't think that's as much of a problem as you think. It's just a matter of extracting code into helper methods to keep the definition of `method_missing` manageable. Maybe something like:

```
 def method_missing(name,*a,&b)
   if has_belongs_to_association?(name)
     invoke_belongs_to_association(name,a,b)
   elsif has_has_many_association?(name)
     invoke_has_many_association(name,a,b)
   # more...
   else
     super
   end
 end
```

Comment: If I understand correctly what you're suggesting with `method_missing` I have to consider that `has_many` and `has_many_through` are right around the corner. And I don't want to overburden method_missing. As for breaking them out into different files I mentioned in the question that I want to work towards the test, not change the test to work for my solution.